# Add Static php file but still can use wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I just want to create one static PHP file in the theme folder, but I can't use `get_header` or anything.

How can I access to the WordPress API with static PHP file?

Comment: Create a custom template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to load the `wp-load.php` file to bootstrap WordPress. This can be done with the following code.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../../wp-load.php';
```

Fair warning, this is not the ideal way to do things like this. You would most-likely be better off using the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook to output different content.